# Ensuring that the callback for a click action on a DOM node contains the information the user saw at the time of the click

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I best ensure that the callback for a click action on a DOM node contains the information the user saw at the time of a click?

If, for example, a click occurs when the event loop is draining a large number of queued events from the job queue, then the click callback will only be evaluated when the queue is drained (I presume), meaning the user interface might have moved on by the time the click callback is run.

Is this a "best-effort" situation, or can I reliably capture what was on the screen at the time of the click?

If a "best-effort" situation, then presumably keeping the running JavaScript highly cooperative (i.e. non-blocking) and minimising the number of events added to the job queue might be helpful?

Finally, do user agents apply any prioritisation to scheduling items on the job queue? So, for example, do events related to user interaction receive any preference to improve perceived responsiveness?

Comment: If the time that the event loop takes until processing the event is longer than the time it takes the monitor to display the image and the user to perceive it, process it, and decide to click, then you're doing something wrong. Don't worry about it.

Comment: I don't think there will be any situation which will produce such scenario. As @Bergi said, Don't worry about it :)

Comment: OK thanks. I'm going to knock up a little experiment to better understand the behavior.